# Send public API versioning across micro service

Tags: microservices, api-gateway, aspnet-api-versioning

I have following architecture

API gateway(REST Public API) --> MBus --> Micro services(Windows Services).

I have implemented the URL based versioning in API Gateway that helps me backward compatibility. Based on the API request API Gateway translate the request to the message bus and send over topic for particular service listening. Now in my micro services that are over the message bus how I manage the Versioning of API for backward compatibility should I send the API version over the message bus from API gateway so that particular service know the version and execute the specific version of the request. What is the standard and ways to manage the API versioning across micro services when micro services are over message bus and not REST based.

Regards,

IK

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing the contract you should use another topic.

Basically you should manage contract on topics.

And you should support both topics until there is no user for the old one.

Comment: Hi Cool, Using another topic but micro service remains same for all the version. Based in topi I can change the functions call with different parameters.  How this version will be propagated from micro service to some provider or connectors that is communicating with some other service so that when some other service like telephony sends the event how would I know this is for version 1,2 or so on. I need versioning in events as well that comes any type when some events occurs in some third party service.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your situation correctly but If you use a different topic for each version you don't need to introduce any versioning into your messages. You can do things as you do in the APIGateway. i.e you have /v2/person and /v1/person in your api gateway then you should have TopicPersonv1 and TopicPersonv2 and you should propagate events to both of them.

Comment: Thansk cool. you mean 
For example API Gateway--> Message bus--> PersonService(V1,V2...) Now when sending request from API gateway to PersonService 
Request handling:
Person Service will susbcribe to both the topic PersonServiceV1, PersonServiceV2 on startup with message bus.
or other approach is we can have wildcard supported topics like PersonService.* and Person service susbcribe to this topic to handle all version. During request /v1/person API Gateway will publish data to PersonService.V1 and Persons service will automatically extract the V1 from the topic. What you think?

Comment: For Event Handling
API Gateway will subscribe with wild card topic for event PersonService.Events.* to handle events coming from all the versions of person service. So person service
will send the event to this topic with PersonService.Events.V1 and then PersonService.Events.V2. API Gateway will
pick the event and send to the consumer based on the version the consumer is using. We push realtime information using Websockets to clients.

What you think I am on right track,

Comment: I would like to make sure about one thing. As you will have 2 topics at the same time you should populate both of them. That means if you are listening both you will receive data twice for the same event. One from TopicV1 and another one from TopicV2. You should be careful how to use them.  I was not aware that APIGateway works both way. When it works one way just the producer for a topic everything is easier. But when you make it also a listener you should now which version the client support and only push that data or on client side you should ignore the version you don't support.

Comment: Thanks Cool. Jut one thing the approach you mentioned in very first comment "the contract you should use another topic." this is standard approach and as compared to send version in message.? I am asking this as I did not find any information on google. If you have any link please share.?

Comment: My guess is as message-based communication is usually an internal communication mechanism and not exposed to outer world, people are just managing these kind of issues for the easiest possible way in their specific systems. That is why I can't tell what is the "standard way" or if there is one. But sending a version information inside a message will not make any difference unless you establish a very stable system on all of your clients in a way that they understand which versions they should consume and set and which ones they should ignore. Release management could also be a big issue.